# Probability of a card being higher than a random card

Tags: probability

Say you have a game that asks you whether you think the next card will be higher.
In this game ace is 1. If the next card is equal to the first one then another random card is taken until the next card is either higher or lower. Suits are disregarded in this game. One deck is used and cards are recycled.

What is the probability of the next card being higher than the previous one. I have thought up this equation but not sure if it is correct:

$$probability = \frac{13 - Rank}{12} * 100% $$

Where Rank is the rank of the current card (from 1 to 13)

Therefore if Rank = Ace, probability  = 100%
Is this equation correct?
Thanks!

Comment: I think that this should be correct. if you want to be sure I suggest you to run some simulation to estimate the probability

Comment: This is a conditional probability (given the rank of the previous card, you can work out the probability), but your question originally sounds like it's after the unconditional probability (you don't know the rank yet, you're trying to work out the probability the second card is larger than the first without seeing either). Is that the case?

Comment: Is this a standard deck of 52 cards?  Do you return a card to the deck after you have taken it?  If so, where in the deck do you put it?

Comment: @JoelReyesNoche Yes it's 52 cards, the card goes to the bottom of the pile. I've edited the post

Comment: @Glen_b I think it's conditional, you pick out a card, and then you work out the probability of the next one being greater.

Comment: Then your equation is fine.

Comment: If after each card is taken it is put on the bottom of the pile, and if you remember which cards have already been taken, then the probabilities change each time you take a card.  To avoid this, you might want to put back the cards in random locations in the deck each time.

Comment: In an equivalent game, after observing the first card *you remove all other cards of that value from the deck* and then proceed. (Although this might change how the game progresses in actual play, it cannot change the outcome: it's just a matter of *when* those cards are ignored.) There can be no ties, there are $52-4$ cards remaining, and $52-4\times\text{rank}$ are higher. This gives $(52-4\times\text{rank})/48=(13-\text{rank})/12$ as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program simulate you game

```
sim=1000000
prob=matrix(data=0,nrow=13,ncol=1)
for(x in 1:13)
{
  print(x)
  for(iter in 1:sim)
  {

    #print(paste(iter/sim,x,sep="   "))
    cards=1:13
    cards=c(cards,cards,cards,cards,cards,cards,cards,cards,cards,cards,cards)# suppose to use more than one deck
    cards=cards[-x]
    y=-1
    while(T)
    {
      y=sample(x=cards,size=1)
      if(y!=x)
        break

      cards=cards[-which(cards==y)[1]]
    }
    if(x<y)
      prob[x]=prob[x]+1
  }
}

prob=prob/sim

rank=1:13

formula=(13-rank)/12 # your formula
#prob=vector(prob)


formula-prob #error between the estimated probability and your formula

 formula-prob
               [,1]
 [1,]  0.000000e+00
 [2,]  1.516667e-04
 [3,]  8.533333e-05
 [4,]  3.830000e-04
 [5,]  7.036667e-04
 [6,]  8.143333e-04
 [7,]  1.070000e-04
 [8,] -1.005333e-03
 [9,]  7.083333e-04
[10,] -5.590000e-04
[11,]  3.986667e-04
[12,]  3.003333e-04
[13,]  0.000000e+00
>
```

The error is small so your formula it's probably right